# Restful api versioning in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api-versioning

I am trying to build a restful api using Laravel-8. Already I have setup Laravel-Passport for api authentication. Now I want to do API versioning for the Laravel-8.

I've heard about Dingo being used with jwt-auth. But I am using laravel passport.

Which api versioning package can I use for the restful api with Laravel Passport auth?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a package for it. You just need to set-up your Laravel project correctly.

Take a look at:

https://medium.com/mestredev/versioning-your-rest-api-with-laravel-646bcc1f70a4